# Hebrew characters appear as question marks in a WP plugin

Tags: wordpress, utf-8

I'm using a WordPress plugin called Vertical News Scroller.
It's working fine in English but when I write in Hebrew I get question marks.
I have no such problem with other plugins or genrally in my Hebrew locallized site.

This plugin has a table called `wp_scroll_news`.

In order to find what is the character set for this table I ran the following query:

```
SELECT CCSA.character_set_name
FROM information_schema.TABLES T, information_schema.COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY CCSA
WHERE CCSA.collation_name = T.table_collation
AND T.table_name = "wp_scroll_news"
```

and I got:
latin1
latin1
latin1

So I used this query:

```
ALTER TABLE wp_scroll_news CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Then I checked again and this time I got:
latin1
latin1
UTF8

After restarting the (WAMP) server and writing new news I still get question marks.
I guess the two remaining latin1 need to be changed as well to UTF8.

How can I do that?

Comment: Your query gives three results because you have have three tables called wp_scroll_news, in different schemas. Add `T.table_schema` to the query to see in which schemas they are.

Comment: OK, but how do I add it? I can't just add `AND T.table_schema`. I have to do something with it, right? I'm a novice with SQL.

Comment: Add it to the list of selected columns, like "select t.table_schema,  ccsa.character_set_name from ...".

Comment: Thanks. I tried it and found out that the two "latin"s are of tables in other databases so they have nothing to do with my case. So if the character set was indeed changed to UTF do you have any idea why I'm still getting question markds instead of Hebrew chars?

Comment: Problem solved. It was indeed one of the other two tables that needed to be changed. I made the original change on a different site than the one I thought I did it on.
Thanks for your help!
If you add your comment as an answer I can accept it.